# Edit one-to-one parent and child together

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have following parent and child models

```cs
    public class Director
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public Home? Home { get; set; }
    }

    public class Home
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int DirectorID { get; set; }
        public Director Director { get; set; } = null!; 
        public string Location { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    }
```

Is there a good way to edit director and home together?
Currently, I always have the ModelState error that `ErrorMessage [string]: "The Director field is required."`

In the htmlcs, I use the following to update the home location inside director edit page.

```
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Director.Home.Location" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Director.Home.Location" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Director.Home.Location" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is - do not use your entities as models (there are multiple reasons for this, including things like [overposting attacks](https://andrewlock.net/preventing-mass-assignment-or-over-posting-in-asp-net-core/)), create special classes for this goal. For example:

```
public class DirectorUpdateModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public HomeUpdateModel Home { get; set; }
}

public class HomeUpdateModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

Map entities to models for views and then map them back to corresponding entities.